# Ruby on Rails and AWS S3 Expiring Download Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am new to coding and I hope I explain this question correctly. Like most people I am starting my journey with Ruby on Rails.

I am trying to request a url from AWS S3 to pass on to the client browser that expires after 20 minutes. I have installed the aws-sdk gem and ran bundle install etc.

I have a welcome controller and an index view. I have the following code in my controller:

```
  class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def doc_download

    require 'aws-sdk'

    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
        access_key_id: 'mykey',
        secret_access_key: 'mykey'
    )

    aws_resource = Aws::S3::Resource::new
    aws_resource.bucket('mynewapp.herokuapp.com').object('1.jpg').presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 20.minutes)

    @download = doc_download

  end

end
```

Then this in my view

```
<p><%= link_to 'Download', @download %></p>
```

But nothing is happening, the page just refreshes when I click on the 'Download' link.

Any help greatly appreciated, spent a couple of days trying to figure it out from many of the different posts that have attempted to complete this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So like this @download = aws_resource.bucket('mynewapp.herokuapp.com').object('1.jpg'‌​).presigned_url(:get‌​, expires_in: 20.minutes)

Comment: thanks, tried it but its the same, there is no error in the console, it seems to just render the link as the index view and refreshes the page

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem using the `aws-sdk-s3` gem (version `1.8.2`). In my case I had to upload a file to S3 and after that presenting an expiring URL to the user. My resulting code looked like that:

```
# Upload a file to S3 and return an expiring URL
# @param [IOStream] file
# @param [String] file_path
# @param optional [Integer] expiring_in_seconds (600)
# @returns [String] expiring and pre-signed URL
def upload_file(file, file_path, expiring_in_seconds = 600)

  # upload file to S3
  client = Aws::S3::Client.new
  client.put_object({
                        body: file,
                        bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
                        key: file_path
                    })

  # create an S3 object reference
  obj =  Aws::S3::Object.new(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'], file_path)

  # create pre-signed url
  obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: expiring_in_seconds)
end
```

Keep in mind that I had the following AWS credentials and settings within my environment variables:

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- `AWS_REGION`
- `S3_BUCKET_NAME`
- `S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Maxence for helping me along the way here, this is the code that works for me:

In my Gemfile

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

My Controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index

    doc_download

  end

  def doc_download

    require 'aws-sdk'

    Aws.config.update(
        region: 'eu-west-2',
        endpoint: 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        access_key_id: 'mykey',
        secret_access_key: 'mykey',
    )

    s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new

    @download = Aws::S3::Object.new(
        key: 'myfilename', bucket_name: 'mybucketname', client: s3_client).presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 60 * 60
    )

  end

end
```

Then to display the link in my index view (from welcome controller)

```
<p><%= link_to 'Download', @download %></p>
```

Just to confirm functionality, this will output a secure expirable link to an s3 bucket for a user to download a file where they may need to pay for it first etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works as I am more familiar with the Paperclip way, but you can try this :

```
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
        access_key_id: 'mykey',
        secret_access_key: 'mykey'
    )

@download = puts Aws::S3::Object.new(
        key: '1.jpg',
        bucket_name: 'mynewapp.herokuapp.com',
        client: s3_client
).presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 60 * 60)
```

I got inspiration from here http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/radosgw/s3/ruby/

Comment: Actually, I tweaked a couple of small things and now for this working! Thanks for the inspiration @Maxence! I will post what I changed a bit later today, it is currently printing to my rails console so will assign it to a variable and test the link. Thanks again!

Comment: Great that's good. I recommend some file upload gem like Paperclip, Carrierwave or Shrine, you won't have to deal with SDK no more.

Answer (score -3):

I think this will now be provided with Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html